# How to make function ExecuteNonQuery to use multi thread to prevent computer hangs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

How can i make my `ExecuteNonQuery` multi threaded and thread safe to prevent my program hanging?

I'm using `ExecuteNonQuery()` to insert, update and delete 10000 records, however my program hangs. To solve this i feel i need to make it multi threaded.

My question is how would i modify the below code to make to make multi threaded and thread safe.

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, DbParameter[] dbprmParameters = null)
{
   return ExecuteNonQuery(sql, null, dbprmParameters);
}
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, IDbConnection dbConnection, DbParameter[] @params = null)
{
   int RecordsCount = 0;

   lock (synObj)
   {

      if (cmd.CommandTimeout < 360)
         cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
      if (sql == "") return 0;

      sql = AnalyizeBooleanFields(sql);
      cmd.CommandText = sql;

      cmd.Parameters.Clear();

      if (@params != null)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < @params.Length; i++)
         {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@params[i]);
         }
      }
      if (dbConnection == null)
      {
         if (WithTransaction)
            dbConnection = BeginTransaction();
         else
            dbConnection = InitializeConnection();
      }
      if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) dbConnection.Open();
      if (WithTransaction) cmd.Transaction = _transaction;
      cmd.Connection = dbConnection;
      RecordsCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      if (!WithTransaction) dbConnection.Close();
   }
   return RecordsCount;
}
public static string AnalyizeBooleanFields(string sql)
{
   switch (DataAccess.Provider)
   {
      case Providers.Access2003:
      case Providers.Access2007:
         sql = sql.Replace("{{1}}", "True");
         sql = sql.Replace("{{0}}", "False");
         break;
      case Providers.SQLServer:
      case Providers.MySQL:
      case Providers.Oracle:
      default:
         sql = sql.Replace("{{1}}", "1");
         sql = sql.Replace("{{0}}", "0");
         break;
   }
   return sql;
}
```

**Note** : i am using Visual Studio 2010 with Sql Server

Comment: I would have suggested that you look into `async` and `await`, but it is not supported completely in Visual Studio 2010. Why are you using such an outdated version?

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker?  Are you working on 10k records one at a time?  You have some questionable code: the lock?  cmd object isn't being created in your function, along with other "global" variables.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more threads is unlikely to help. The problem is that you are sending your updated to the database one at a time.

The query to update one record is getting issued to the database, and then the calling program blocks while waiting for the database query to complete. (And if it is on a different machine will also incur a network delay in both directions).

A much better approach would be to store your updates into a list, and then issue a single database request that updates multiple records at once. For example, upload a table of changes, and then issue a single query that updates/deletes your actual data table in a single statement. Refer to the bulk operations documentation for the database you actually care about.

For example, for SQL Server, consider using [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).